# Specflow table column binding prevent Nulls

Tags: bdd, specflow

Given the following code:

```
public class Bob {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public decimal Height { get; set; }
}

Feature: Bob checker

Scenario: Check Bob
  Given I have the following Bob
     | Name   | Age | Hieght |
     | Robert | 63  | 1.87   |
  When . . . . 
  Then . . . . 

[Given(@"I have the following Bob")]
public void IHaveTheFollowingBob(Table table) {
    var bob = table.CreateInstance<Bob>();
}
```

You'l notice the word 'Height' is not spelt correctly in the table.  The `CreateInstance` method will still work but the 'Height' on the Bob object will be 0 or for reference type, null.

Is there a way to make SpecFlow fail if the column doesn't bind to the Type provided.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as throwing error if there is a column that does not match any of the class properties.

However there is a work-arround. You may implement a method to check if there is an "invalid" column to prevent typos:

```
    [Given("I have the following Bob")]
    public void TestMethod1(Table table)
    {
        AssertAllTableColumnsMatch<Bob>(table);

        var bob = table.CreateInstance<Bob>();
    }

    public void AssertAllTableColumnsMatch<T>(Table table)
    {
        foreach (var header in table.Header)
        {
            bool columnHeaderMatches = HasProperty(typeof(T), header);

            Assert.IsTrue(columnHeaderMatches,
                string.Format("The column header [{0}] does not match any property of the type [{1}]",
                header, typeof(T).Name));
        }
    }

    private bool HasProperty(Type obj, string propertyName)
    {
        return obj.GetProperty(propertyName) != null;
    }
```

The following error will be thrown:
`-> error: Assert.IsTrue failed. The column header [Hieght] does not match any property of the type [Bob]`

The method simply iterates all the columns and checks if the provided type has such property.

Answer (score 0):

I should RTFM. `table.CompareToInstance(bob);` Will fail if the Property is not there or is not populated the correctly.  If you use this in conjuction with `table.CreateInstance` you will get failures where there are nulls.  Leaving Q&A here just in case anyone else has brain fail.

[SpecFlow Assist Helper, CompareToInstance](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/SpecFlow-Assist-Helpers#comparetoinstance)

If you have have complex types you can represent them in the table and use `IValueRetriever`and `IValueComparer` [extensions](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/SpecFlow-Assist-Helpers#extensions)

For example consider the following micky mouse code:

```
public class Bob {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public decimal Height { get; set; }
}

public class BobModel {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public decimal Height { get; set; }
}

Feature: Bob checker

Scenario: Check Bob
  Given I have the following Bob
     | Name   | Age | Hieght |
     | Robert | 63  | 1.87   |
  When I map this to the model
  Then Bob the model looks like this
     | Name   | Age | Height |
     | Robert | 63  | 1.87   |

[Given(@"I have the following Bob")]
public void IHaveTheFollowingBob(Table table) {
    var bob = table.CreateInstance<Bob>();
}

[When(@"I map this to the model")]
public void IMapThisToTheModel() {
   sut = production.Map(bob);
}

[Then(@"Bob the model looks like this") {
public void BobTheModelLooksLikeThis(Table table) {
   table.CompareToInstance<BobModel>(sut);
}
```

In this instance if there was a typo in the second table it would fail saying it can't find the property.  If there is a typo in the first table then this will still be null but the assertion will fail. No false positives

Comment: How do you use CompareToInstance(..) since you don't have the instance which you try to create in the step ? If you throw a dummy instance the comparing will throw an exception.

Comment: @valentinvs just edited the answer to be more complete.